# Set lombok logger properties?

Tags: java, logging, lombok

I have a simple Java project without any framework using maven as my project management. I have imported lombok and using its logging [@sl4j] but the log are only rendered in console.

Is there a way to set/change lombok logger properties ?

Thank you

Comment: Slf4j is a facade and uses a logging library behind the scenes. Find out which logging library you have in your classpath (log4j, logback...) then add a corresponding properties/xml file into your classpath. It should get automatically detected.

Comment: @aksappy how can I tell which one I have??

Comment: Oh wait nevermind found it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `logback` you can add dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and provide logback.xml

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="some.package" level="TRACE"/>

</configuration>
```